# Mysql Database design - Optimizing

Tags: mysql

I'm creating this database to store historical information of some equipment in our network.

I have the following tables:

Data - that has the following 24 fields..

1) ID , TIME , Date, Network , Downstream_Max , Downstream_Min, Downstream_Avg  .. etc

Remote_Count

1) ID, TIME , Date, Network , Active, Inactive, Test

Network

1) ID, NetworkID, NetworkName

I want to create a view that will look like the following

Date, NetworkName, NetworkID, Active, Inactive, Test, Downstream_MAx, Downstream_Min

My question is..

The following query I created the most efficient way?

```
select 
  `d`.`Date` AS `Date`,
  `n`.`NetworkName` AS `NetworkName`,
  `d`.`Network` AS `ID`,
  `r`.`Active` AS `Active`,
  `r`.`Inactive` AS `Inactive`,
  `r`.`Test` AS `Test`,
  `d`.`Downstream_Max` AS `Downstream_Max`,
  `d`.`Downstream_Min` AS `Downstream_Min`,
  `d`.`Downstream_Avg` AS `Downstream_Avg`, 
from ((`Data` `d` join `Remote_Count` `r` on((`d`.`ID` = `r`.`ID`))) 
join `Network` `n` on((`n`.`NetworkID` = `d`.`Network`))) 
order by `d`.`Date`
```

Comment: run `explain` on the query. That's the only way the question can be answered. It will show you if the query uses appropriate indexes and if there are any slow operations

Comment: I'd probably store Date and Time as one DATETIME column.

Comment: @Arth I should have been more specific, TIME is the actually TIME that the data is inserted, DATE is what week. I'm wondering if my select query can be done another way.

Comment: @user3931492 your query looks pretty darn efficient, you should look at indexing too. I still prefer one DATETIME for the created time, you can get the week out if you need, I'd only separate for performance. On the readability front.. you should be able to write this without any backticks or parentheses and your column aliases currently do nothing.